# ¿Como cambiar toolbar al cambiar fragment en Android?

Tags: android, toolbar

Tengo una navegación inferior y cuando cambio de un fragment a otro quiero que la toolbar superior cambien las opciones.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Has intentado algo?

Comment: Te refieres a como funciona whattsap ?

Answer (score 1):

Para poder realizar esto, debes llamar a la función **setHasOptionsMenu** en el fragment, en la función **onCreateView**. Luego haces un override de las funciones que agregan las opciones en el toolbar.

Ejemplo:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_example, container, false); // TU LAYOUT
}



@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_example,menu); // TU MENU
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.optAdd: // TU OPCION
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: antes de responder a este tipo de preguntas, es recomendable esperar a que el autor muestre que intentó/investigó y con qué está teniendo problemas específicamente. [Es.so] no es un reemplazo de Google

Comment: Estoy totalmente de acuerdo contigo, pero la mayoría de las respuestas y explicaciones están en ingles, entonces como hacemos para ayudar a los demas? A mi me llego un mensaje que stackoverflow en español necesita ayuda, solo me meti para ayudar en mis tiempos libres....